# Access 2016 parameter issues

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I have a database of products. One of the tables is a supplier history listing who we have purchased each product from and when. Suddenly the table for supplier history is asking me for parameters. I've been using it for a long time and it never did this before. Please note this is happening in a table, not a query. The table does have two relationships to other tables but again this never happened before.

Answer (score 0):

> Inspect expressions in a table
>
> If Access displays the Enter Parameter Value dialog box every time that you open a table, the incorrect expression is most likely in the Row Source property of a Lookup field in that table.
>
> 1. Right-click the table in the Navigation Pane, and then select Design View.
> 2. To determine if a field is a Lookup field, select the field name, and then under Field Properties, select the Lookup tab. If the tab contains a Row Source property box, then the field is a Lookup field. Examine the Row Source property. If it contains an SQL statement, then one of the identifiers in the statement may be incorrect, and causing the Enter Parameter Value dialog box to appear.
>
> Note: A table can have multiple Lookup fields, so be sure to check the Lookup tab for each field.

Found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Why-does-Access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-0e71a1dd-e498-49a1-9e2e-356538d226ff) from Microsoft. This might help point you in the right direction.